# making table in loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

Please help,

I write the loop. However, the data1 result is not the data frame that I want. data1 should be like this:

```
newcol_0.000001 newcol_0.00001  newcol_0.0001   newcol_0.001    newcol_0.01 newcol_0.1  newcol_01
2.50E-07    2.50E-06    2.50E-05    0.0025  0.025   0.25    1
2.53E-07    2.53E-06    2.53E-05    0.002531969 0.025319693 0.253196931 1
2.56E-07    2.56E-06    2.56E-05    0.002564767 0.025647668 0.256476684 1
2.60E-07    2.60E-06    2.60E-05    0.002598425 0.025984252 0.25984252  1
2.63E-07    2.63E-06    2.63E-05    0.002632979 0.026329787 0.263297872 1
2.67E-07    2.67E-06    2.67E-05    0.002668464 0.026684636 0.266846361 1
2.70E-07    2.70E-06    2.70E-05    0.002704918 0.02704918  0.270491803 1
2.74E-07    2.74E-06    2.74E-05    0.002742382 0.027423823 0.274238227 1
2.78E-07    2.78E-06    2.78E-05    0.002780899 0.027808989 0.278089888 1
2.82E-07    2.82E-06    2.82E-05    0.002820513 0.028205128 0.282051282 1
```

```
se=seq(-0.4,0.1,length.out=100)
t=100
gamma=c(0.0000001,0.000001,0.00001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1)
for (i in 1:length(gamma)) {
  newcol <- ((gamma[i]*(2.718^((se+gamma[i])*t)))-gamma[i])/((gamma[i]*(2.718^((se+gamma[i])*t)))+se)
  data1 <- rbind(data1, newcol)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
se=seq(-0.4,0.1,length.out=100)
t=100
data1 <- data.frame(matrix(NA , nrow = 100))
gamma=c(0.0000001,0.000001,0.00001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1)
for (i in 1:length(gamma)) {
    newcol <- ((gamma[i]*(2.718^((se+gamma[i])*t)))-gamma[i])/((gamma[i]*(2.718^((se+gamma[i])*t)))+se)
    data1[[i]] <- newcol
}
colnames(data1) <- paste0("newcol_" ,gamma)
```